# ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3 but not in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a project I want to run on different machines without the need to modify the `PYTHONPATH` enviroment variable. My projects structure is as follows:

```
awesome_project/
  data/
  scripts/
    __init__.py
    predict/
      importer/
        __init__.py
      __init__.py
      predict.py
    train/
      importer/
        __init__.py
      __init__.py
      train.py
    utils/
      __init__.py
      configuration.py
```

In my predict and train code I need to import variables defined in the configuration file inside utils. In Python 2 I defined the `importer` module, in which the `__init__.py` had the following code:

```
import sys
from os import getcwd
from os.path import sep

root_path = sep.join(getcwd().split(sep)[:-2])
sys.path.append(root_path)
```

And it worked as a charm. I imported the variables as: `from scripts.utils.configuration import models_path`, but now I'm migrating my code to Python 3 and this does not work at all, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scripts.utils.configuration import models_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.utils'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in `sys.path` just before the offending commit?

Comment: @Goyo it's a vector as follows: `[<path to the predict code>, <bunch of python paths>, '/home/ubuntu/carlos/permit_classification']` The last one is the one I want to add and where it shoudl look for the module `scripts`

Comment: So `awesome_project` is actually `/home/ubuntu/carlos/permit_classification` and the module you want to import is `/home/ubuntu/carlos/permit_classification/scripts/utils/configuration.py`?

Comment: @Goyo correct, I noticed the discrepancy after the commentary

Comment: Can you import just `scripts`? Maybe there is another module / package shadowing yours.

Comment: @Goyo I imported scripts as `import scripts` and got no error there.